# How do Curry sentences fit into the following "pattern"?

Tags: curry-paradox

Sometimes,<sup>1</sup> we are tempted to deny at least compositional meaningfulness to [some self-referential sentences](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/#ParSelRef) like, "[This sentence is false](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/)," or, "[This sentence is not known to be true](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemic-paradoxes/#KnoPar)" (i.e. we grant the component words their meaning but deny additional meaning to their sentential combination).  However, it seems as if there is a simple erotetic proof-by-distinction that the sentences as wholes are specifically meaningful (that is, by evaluating them as wholes, we find a distinction between them, which distinction is a condition of their meaningfulness); the trick is to convert them, one and all,<sup>2</sup> into questions, and then check what their correct answer would be:

1. (Base case) "Is this sentence true?" → *No, because questions aren't truth-apt in the first place.*
2. "Is this sentence false?" → *No, for the same reason as (1)*.
3. "Is this sentence not true?" → *Yes, for the same reason as (1)*.
4. "Is this sentence provably false?" → *No, because (4) isn't truth-apt*.
5. "Is this sentence not provably true?" → *Yes, because (5) isn't truth-apt*.
6. "Is this sentence provably not true?" → *Yes, because (6) isn't truth-apt*.
7. "Is this sentence known to be false?" → *No, because (7) isn't truth-apt*.
8. "Is this sentence not known to be true?" → *Yes, because (8) isn't truth-apt*.
9. "Is this sentence known to be not true?" → *Yes, because (9) isn't truth-apt*.

The [modal versions of the liar/honest sentences](https://johannesstern.github.io/publication/stern-2023/ModLiar.pdf) conform to a similar "pattern":

10. "Is it possible that this sentence is true?" → *No, because (10) isn't truth-apt*.
11. "Is it possible that this sentence is not true?" → *Yes, because (11) isn't truth-apt*.
12. "Is it not possible that this sentence is true?" → *Yes, because (12) isn't truth-apt*.

But so I'm not sure about (13) modulo the above:

13. ["If this very sentence is true, then is time infinite?"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/curry-paradox/)

Since it's (part of) a question, then the antecedent isn't discharged (since it's not true), so the consequent doesn't follow? **But so do we say, "No, because not truth-apt," or, "Yes, because not truth-apt," or something else, hereto?** It would seem to me that [the logic of conditionals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-conditionals/) is relevant to this question in the sense of that logic fixing the discrepancy, such as it is, between categorical and conditional questions "in the first place."

---

<sup>1</sup>See e.g. Szangolies[[18](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10668.pdf)] or Richard[[01](https://atrium.lib.uoguelph.ca/server/api/core/bitstreams/984b1ebc-2c37-4f90-9535-1f40c013d944/content)] for critical examples of this maneuver.

<sup>2</sup>[Liar cycles](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/#LiarCycl) are such as, "(1) Sentence 2 is true; (2) Sentence 1 is false." Now convert either (1) or (2) into a question, e.g. go to, "(1) Is sentence 2 true? (2) Sentence 1 is false." However, in this event, (1) is no longer a truth-apt assertion but is a question, so the cycle "breaks down." (This way of looking at liar paradoxes is more or less a balancing or fusion of [dialogical logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-dialogical/) and the [revision theory of truth](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-revision/).)

Comment: Can you site someone who says that the sentence isn't meaningful? I know it is often said not to be a proposition or not to have a truth value, but I don't think I've ever read anyone who says it does not have a meaning.

Comment: @DavidGudeman [here's one example from arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10668.pdf): "This is analogous to trying to solve the liar-paradox
by deciding that ‘this sentence is false’, is neither false
nor true, but meaningless. However, then, we can formulate ‘this sentence is false or meaningless’, which must
either be true, or not; but if it is true, then it is false or
meaningless, yet if it is false or meaningless, then it is
true." "This sentence is false or meaningless," is one of the basic "revenge" sentences in this connection.

Comment: @DavidGudeman There's a (if you ask me, silly) claim in the truth-conditional theory of semantics that any sentence that has not truth value (like Russell's paradox) is meaningless, because meaning is taken as being wholly dependent on the existence of a true or false truth value. In that way, a logician's truth-conditional semantics doesn't make the same claim about meaning as another linguist's semantic theory. Our intuitions are of course that RP has both meaning (since it has lexical and sentential meaning) AND carries a paradox.

Comment: >"Is this sentence false?" Which sentence?

Comment: @JuliusH. I am sympathetic to some, but not all, of your proposed edits. I don't have a problem with speaking in the first-person plural, here, since I identify with the community of logicians who study these matters in this kind of earnest. But I will see about some of the other edits (like rearranging the image of my supposed "pattern").

Answer (score 2):

I do not like the sentence being its own precursor. That has a nasty feeling about it. Let us instead consider what a logic circuit might do. There are four possible states...

(1) This sentence has five words. (True)

(2) This sentence has six words. (False)

(3) This sentence is true.  (Bistable)

(4) This sentence is false. (Astable)

The bistable case is the flip-flop circuit: if it is True then it is True; if it is False then it is False. The astable case is the oscillator, where there is no stable state.

It should be possible to create more complex sentences which refer to themselves in more complicated ways, but for the simple case where the sentence has two states (True or False) then these four cases cover the possibilities.

I have not tackled the case where a statement is allowed to be its own precursor, so I have not dealt with Curry's actual paradox. I read this [article on Curry's paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/curry-paradox/). But if my solution is complete, then I am left wondering whether the paradox arises from allowing a sentence to be its own precursor.

Comment: The bistability/astability distinction seems of a piece with the [revision theory of truth](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-revision/), which I am sympathetic to. I will look into the application of the revision theory to Curry's paradox.